# Erro de lógica no PHP em contrução if elseif else

Tags: php, lógica, controle-de-fluxo

Eu tenho um simples formulário de e-mail com reCaptcha.

Para evitar de o usuário enviar o e-mail e ficar dando F5 e mandando o mesmo e-mail várias vezes, eu fiz um redirecionamento em um script php. Mas existe um erro de lógica nesse script, pois apesar de as duas variáveis serem falsas ele está enviando o e-mail igual!

**Perceba que a estrutura do script deve ser assim mesmo** (*if variavel == false, elseif, else* e não *if variavel == true, else if, else* como de costume), pois para redirecionar a página eu mudo o cabeçalho do php e essa deve ser a primeira coisa a ser feita antes de dar comandos de impressão (print, echo, html fora do script).

Aqui está o meu código, note que ele imprime as duas variáveis falsas e imprime "tudo ok".

```
<?php

$ok_post = false;
$ok_captcha = false;

echo "ok_post = ", (int)$ok_post;
echo "<br>ok_captcha = ", (int)$ok_captcha;

if ((!ok_post && !ok_captcha) || (!ok_post && ok_captcha)) {

  echo '<br>Formulário vazio.';

} elseif (!ok_captcha && ok_post) {

  echo '<br>Captcha vazio.';

} else {

  echo '<br>Tudo ok!';

}

?>
```

output:

```
ok_post = 0
ok_captcha = 0
Tudo ok!
```

**EDIT: O seguinte script python funciona como deveria, então cheguei a conclusão que estou usando errado algum operador PHP, mas não sei qual.**

```
ok_post = False
ok_captcha = False

print 'ok_post', ok_post
print 'ok_captcha', ok_captcha

if not ok_post and not ok_captcha or not ok_post and ok_captcha:
  print 'formulario vazio'
elif not ok_captcha and ok_post:
  print 'captcha vazio'
else:
  print 'ok'
```

output:

```
ok_post False
ok_captcha False
formulario vazio
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seu erro foi simples, você não colocou o `$` das `variáveis` no momento da verificação no `if` e `elseif` .

***Script*** correto:

```
<?php

$ok_post = false;
$ok_captcha = false;

echo "ok_post = ", (int)$ok_post;
echo "<br>ok_captcha = ", (int)$ok_captcha;

if ((!$ok_post && !$ok_captcha) || (!$ok_post && $ok_captcha)) {

  echo '<br>Formulário vazio.';

} elseif (!$ok_captcha && $ok_post) {

  echo '<br>Captcha vazio.';

} else {

  echo '<br>Tudo ok!';

}

?>
```

Comment: Puxa, como eu não enxerguei isso? Eu pensei que estivesse escrevendo em python. Hahaha. Obrigado.

Comment: As vezes estamos tão dentro do código que acontecem essas coisas, por isso é bom compartilhar. Já perdi 5horas por causa de uma `,` hahaha faz parte. Abs.